# Set text after a three.js scene defined by a <div id="mainWindow">

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have coded a small Three.js animation that I put i following way in my HTML page :

```
  <div id="mainWindow" class="popup_block">

  <!-- Javascript for simulation -->
  <script src="../temp/webgl-debug.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/TrackballControls.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/dat.gui.js"></script>
  <script src="./main_simulation.js"></script>

<br>
This is a test : I want to put text below the "div id="mainWindow", not above like here :<br>

How could I do that ???


</div>
```

where I handle the Three.js scene of "**mainWindow**" in **main_simulation.js**

Unfortunately, I can't get to put after `</div>` some text or other HTML elements : they are systematically put above the `<div id="mainWindow">... </div>` block

You can see this issue on the following link :

[Can't put text below  Three.js](http://beulu.com/test/info/text_after_three_js/index.html)

Maybe this problem comes from the fact that I am loading JS scripts at the bottom of HTML page but I am not sure.

If I load JS scripts in `<head>` section, I can't make appear the Three.js scene.

Could anyone give me a trick to put text after the main div of Three.js ?

Regards

**UPDATE 1 :**

I have also tried with :

```
  <div id="mainWindow" class="popup_block"></div>

  <!-- Javascript for simulation -->
  <script src="../temp/webgl-debug.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/TrackballControls.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="../temp/dat.gui.js"></script>
  <script src="./main_simulation.js"></script>
         <br>
This is a test : I want to put text below the "div id="mainWindow", not above like here :<br>

How could I do that ???
```

But the problem is still present

**UPDATE 2 :**

Here's an illustration of my issue :

[image: Text above three.js div and not below]

In HTML source, the text is located below the three.js div, but the rendering makes put it above.

**UPDATE 3 :**

[image: illustration]

Comment: Do You want an element under the three.js renderer div ?

Like i did here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/vLLdLzo6/1/?

Comment: -@Piotr Adam Milewski Yes, I want to continue adding text and simply filling the rest of the HTML page, I mean below the three.js div. Thanks for your answer, but you display a text instead of div (by clicking on button) : I just want to put the text under the three.js div, not instead of it. thanks

Comment: See my **UPDATE :3** . I don't want to hide or not the text, I want it to appear always after my three.js animation, whatever user clicks or not on the image. I show you in **UPDATE :3** what I would like to get.

Comment: You mean below like the button, or under, like the div here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/vLLdLzo6/4/ ? is there an option of having a fixed div?

Comment: Have you seen the last image to illutrate what I would like ? How can I make fixed the div of three.js ?

Comment: i saw it after my comment, now its better ? https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/vLLdLzo6/6/

Comment: ok your last jsfiddle seems to be good. Is the secret with CSS you used, i.e : #below {
  position: fixed;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  top:260px;
  left:100px;
} How did you force text to be below the three.js div ??? regards

Comment: how about using the 'relative' option from my anwser ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152483/discussion-between-piotr-adam-milewski-and-youpilat13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, its not really a matter of three.js, but there is still an important issue to address.

Whatever functions You have, either plain image positioning, or three.js placing the renderer in a div, It's easy to lose track of what is appended where.

It can happen when the `html` skeleton is being rather scarce, for most of the page is created in **js**. It's a bit unclear to anyone but the original developer, so he needs to keep track of what is going on. Imo this is a bit impractical.

I wouldn't create elements in the body in js, I'd rather append them to existing wrapper containers, so I could easily manage them with any css:

```
<div id="mainWindow"></div>
  <div id="image"></div>
  <div id="below"></div>
```

if You switch the target div from the body, to #image, You can rearrange them however You like, without making any changes in the js code, which could cause a chain of unpredicted behaviour.

Now the desired arrangement could be made using the `position:relative;` css property.